# how do i perform some action on enity a when some action entity b happen

Tags: java, jpa

Say i have three entity(table) **Booking**, **wallet** and **Account** with *post* action i have created a controller that adds a row in Booking table. Primary key of Account table act as foreign key to both Wallet and Booking. One account can have one wallet but multiple bookings can be done by it. Now when i create entry in wallet  table i can give certain amount of balance(variable) and in Booking table there is a column of amount/cost by user.

Now my problem is how do i update the wallet balance column whenever i create a new booking?

I am new in JPA so please ask me for more details if you did not understood my question.

Comment: .  If you have a @OneToOne relation between Account and Wallet, then when you save (Account), this (account) must have (Wallet) information, and it will be stored automatically into the Wallet Table.

Comment: It all depends on your setup and requirements, but I can think of at least a couple of options: 1) like SMA said use `save(Account)` and update the wallet balance (probably preferable since this needs to go into one transaction), 2) use a DB trigger to update the wallet balance (you might need to reread the entities after the transaction though), 3) publish an event using CDI/Spring etc. and have a service consume it and update wallet balance (this decouples both operations and might not meet your requirements).